# In R build a tree and find the Cost of each branch

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart

I am new to the R thing.

I have been building this decision tree in TreeAge and it's OK.
Now, i have this Tree here:

I have this decision to make:

```
                A patient with Cancer 

                    /                   \
         Cure Immediately              Wait a little
        /                \            /              \
     Alive              Dead        Alive             Dead
 D_p_Alive                #            #             p_progress
```

The values below are the probabilities for each decision... could you please give me a hand on how to build this tree, i sincerely have no clue, even after going 1 week on reading..

I read about decision trees, how to prune them, about rpart, cran etc...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you check pages like [this](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cart.html)?

Comment: I've tried pages like this:
http://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/system/files/cart_ex.pdf
I want to manually grow the tree i suppose... but i don't know, they use some summary, i already have my values...

Comment: Yes, i've already seen that page, but the issue is, i already have my values, i don't have a dataset and waiting to extract info, i already have probabilities and other variables...

Comment: If you search for Q here with "decision tree [r]" there's many questions. Maybe [this faq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) helps to provide people here with a testcase. It's always good to publish a concise testcase and code example to motivate people to provide answers.

Comment: Well thank you, i went through that, hm, i just have a question please, so i understand... I should build my own dataframe? But i just have some variables, i already have the tree structure, i just need to build it in R, so can i manually set up the tree?

Comment: My point is: You state that you have read a lot and you have shown tree structure, but you haven't shown us what you've tried to code in `R` so far. People might think you want the community to do the work for you. Maybe, post what you have tried, possibly the errors you got, and then ask specific questions on that. Then people here can point our why it does not work and how to improve. But this Q is just 2 hours old at this time, so maybe you just have to wait for others to come online. I'm currently not into `R`, and never worked with D-Trees in R before, so cannot help here.